# How compile c code with python header file

Tags: c, msys2

I downloaded python source code using the command

```
 git clone https://github.com/python/cpython
```

Now I created a `main.c` like so

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <python.h>

int main(void)
{
    
    return 0;
}
```

when I try to compile using this command

```
gcc main.c -L /f/<redacted>/cpython/Lib -I /f/<redacted>/cpython/Include  -lpython
```

I get this error

```
$ gcc main.c -L /f/<redacted>/cpython/Lib -I /f/<redacted>/cpython/Include  -lpython
In file included from main.c:2:
F:/<redacted>/cpython/Include/python.h:12:10: fatal error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
   12 | #include "pyconfig.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I know that `pyconfig.h` can be obtained using `sudo apt install python-dev` on Linux, so I tried `pacman -S python-devel` but this does not seem to fix the issue

I also tried to use `locate pyconfig.h` to link it using the `-I` but it is nowhere to be found

My machine is a windows 10 and I am using  `MSYS2`with`MINGW64` to compile this code

Comment: If you're using MINGW64 environment, all packages and compilers you install need to be prefixed with `mingw-w64-x64_64-`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat like so `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-python-devel`

Comment: It seems there's no such package, but there is `mingw-w64-x86_64-python`, which includes `pyconfig.h`.

Comment: Have you actually compiled cpython? I mean the library files are not just magically going to be there. They need to be compiled first. And the `pyconfig.h` will not be in the `Include` directory but in the `cpython` directory. What instructions did you use?

Comment: @Cheatah as i understand i have to compile the python files into a dll and then link that with the `main.c` ? 
i am not using any instructions, trying to compile with the knowledge i have

Comment: @Cheatah MSYS2 should include a prebuilt one, so you don't need to compile it yourself.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat my goal is to have a python interpreter inside the `main.c` planning to take a python code and running it from the compile `main.c`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I don't know much about MSYS2, but if that is true, wouldn't that mean that the `git clone ... cpython` was not needed?

Comment: Yep, I don't think it's needed.

Comment: How would you have python interpreter inside a c executable